# Can I remove the Ctrl+W shortcut in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, shortcuts

I'm looking for some way to unplug the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut in Nautilus that closes the window. The reason is that when I drag a file out of Nautilus into my text editor, I almost always close it after reading some snippet for about 3 seconds. But when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close my file, Nautilus wants to be the application in focus, so it takes the keystroke and closes the Nautilus window.

It would actually be better for Nautilus to release focus to the drop target when a file is dragged out--or even better, never take focus at all, just be visible but not a focusable window. But this seems like it would be difficult to accomplish, so I'd be happy with a way to turn off <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. Does anyone know of a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Keystrokes will go to whichever window has focus. The easiest thing to do is simply click once on the text editor after drag & dropping your file to it. That will give the window focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> shortcut in Nautilus by adding the following line to `~/.config/nautilus/accels` and then rebooting:

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Close" "")
```

This sets the keyboard shortcut (accelerator) for the close action to nothing instead of the default of `"<Primary>w"`.